# MySQL optimizing sql join query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I was asked this at an interview to do on a whiteboard, and my solution seems far too complex for a white board answer.

I have two tables, one has ids and names as table Person, the other has id, person_id, and friend_id as table Friend. a row in Friend table signifies a friendship between two people. I would like to find all instances of friendships for "Gina" without knowing her id.

I came up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM
(SELECT name1 AS name FROM
    (SELECT p1.name AS name1, p2.name AS name2 FROM friend f INNER JOIN person p1 ON f.person_id = p1.id INNER JOIN person p2 ON f.friend_id = p2.id WHERE p2.name LIKE 'Gina' OR p1.name LIKE 'Gina') AS group1
UNION ALL
SELECT name2 AS name FROM
    (SELECT p1.name AS name1, p2.name AS name2 FROM friend f INNER JOIN person p1 ON f.person_id = p1.id INNER JOIN person p2 ON f.friend_id = p2.id WHERE p2.name LIKE 'Gina' OR p1.name LIKE 'Gina') AS group2)
AS combo WHERE name <> 'Gina';
```

I don't think well on whiteboard and this cannot be the best solution for this. Can anyone optimize this?

Made a sqlfiddle for a couple of friends to mess around with afterwards:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d10b/16

Comment: They asked you to do a simple `JOIN` statement.

Comment: regardless of what was asked, is there a way to optimize my answer for what im asking

Comment: @hermanthriller did you find an answer here?  Is there more I could help with?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want are the names of people who list Gina as a friend, this will do it.

```
SELECT person.name
  FROM person
  JOIN friend on friend.person_id = person.id
 WHERE friend.friend_id = (SELECT id FROM person WHERE name = 'Gina')
;
```

Although, with only three people, you can't really test the contra. A better test would be to add a a fourth person that should not show up in the result set.

**Update**

Given your updated schema, this gets both friends of Gina and people who have Gina as a friend. [It runs at least as fast or *slightly* faster](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53cb6/8) than yours. In my experience, nine times out of ten, stating the query as simply as possible and letting the database figure it out is the best way to go.

```
SELECT person.name
  FROM friend
  JOIN person ON person.id = friend.person_id
 WHERE friend.friend_id = (SELECT id FROM person WHERE name = 'Gina')
UNION
SELECT person.name
  FROM friend
  JOIN person ON person.id = friend.friend_id
 WHERE friend.person_id = (SELECT id FROM person WHERE name = 'Gina')
;
```

Comment: i added 4th name and relationships, yours works and is way simpler.

Comment: I have a feeling this might be fast too

Comment: Hmmm it actually works, how does this work when friend.person_id is Gina's id? It is because there are 2 rows for Fred, but if you delete the 1st row in friend table, this wouldn't work anymore

Comment: so, i think this one is actually slightly wrong. it only finds friends of gina's if she shows up in the friend_id column, but not if she shows up in the person_id column. try this fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53cb6/2

Comment: @hermanthriller yeah, the question never explained how reciprocation worked in this schema, so it's a little open-ended there

Comment: Your new fiddle clarifies the situation. Thanks. I updated to take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I am not sure which one is faster... You have to benchmark...

```
SET @gina_id=(SELECT id FROM person WHERE name = 'Gina');
SELECT DISTINCT person.name
FROM person
JOIN friend on (friend.person_id = person.id or friend.friend_id=person.id)
WHERE (friend.friend_id = @gina_id
OR friend.person_id = @gina_id)
AND person.id != @gina_id
```

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/962db/3